# What's the meaning of "or so I read", usually at the end of a sentence?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I didn't find anything online about this term and I can't quite remember where I caught it the first time.

Can you please elaborate where it is used and what it exactly means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It distances you from the statement. You might want to do this in a couple of scenarios:

- You don't know whether what you've read is true or not
- You have first-hand knowledge of something, but to admit this would embarrass or incriminate you